# how to override a border on a TR when there is a border on a TD

Tags: hover, border, html-table, tablerow

Given the following, how do I get the TR border to override the TD border.
`!important` doesn't seem to do the trick. The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/) is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/).

```
<head>
        <style>
            * { font-family: tahoma; }
                table { 
                    border-collapse: collapse; 
                    background-color: rgb(202,217,234);
                }
                table td {
                    font-size: 12pt;
                    padding: .5rem;
                    border: 1px solid rgb(079,129,189);
                }
                table tr:hover {
                    border: 1px solid crimson !important;
                }
                *#first { border: 1px solid black; }

        </style>
<body>

        <table>
                <col id="first" />
                <col id="second" />
                <col id="third" />
                <thead>
                        <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                                <td>One</td><td>Fred</td><td>Jim</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Two</td><td>Demo</td><td>Item</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Three</td><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the trick in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/6/), but without cells border. My CSS look like:

```
        * { font-family: tahoma; }
            table { 
                border-collapse: collapse; 
                background-color: rgb(202,217,234);
            }
            *#first { border: 1px solid black; }
            *#second, *#third {
                border: 1px solid rgb(079,129,189);
            }
            table td {
                font-size: 12pt;
                padding: .5rem;
            }

            table tr:hover {
                border: 1px solid crimson;
            }
             table tr:hover td {
                border: none;
            }
```

Another idea [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/8/) which works find, is to give 2px for the Hover border.

```
            /*Adding this*/
            table tr {
               border: 1px solid rgb(079,129,189);
            }                
            /* Changing this*/
            table tr:hover {
                border: 2px solid crimson;
            }
```

Ok, so the solution is to use the `ridge` border type for cells border:

```
table td {
   font-size: 12pt;
   padding: .5rem;
   border: 1px ridge rgb(079,129,189);
}
```

Comment: I know, it's a tricky problem!
I have tried a few things. I need the border on the TD though, so that's a problem. I have discovered that if you set the TD border style to ridge instead of solid, that the solid of the TR will override, and that seems to work quite well. Take a look (http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/9/). This seems be a good solution, but it will only work if the border is 1px, which it is!
Let's see if there are any other suggestions, otherwise I will accept your answer, as it's close.

Comment: Here is the same one with a background, as I intend to use it.
http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/10

Comment: It works in IE9/10 (http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/10/). I am not sure about previous versions, but to be honest I don't worry as much as I used to about IE. I hint to users to replace or upgrade old versions of IE. I guess if you need the older versions it might be a problem.

Comment: I have made one more attempt, this time with a little javascript, and it works in all browsers and any border width. You would think this would be easier. The corners aren't perfect, but it's good enough.
http://jsfiddle.net/rhKda/15/